# Unable to Get Multiple Select Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I'm trying to pull the selected options through AJAX into a django view.  It's only printing out the first selected option, not the 2nd or 3rd and so on.  If I pass a dictionary in the ajax, it receives it fine in the view.  So the error is not in the view, since the getlist is gathering the dictionary.  However, when I use the variable from the template.html, it only won't get more than 1 value.  I've tried adding "[]" after the name and id, but no success.  I've also tried some javascript from other answers on SO, but no results.

---

template.html

```
           <div id="manytomany-container">
                {% if custommany1.name != 'None' %}
                    <label>{{ custommany1.name }}:</label>
                    <p><select name="custommany1" multiple="multiple" id="company-custommany1">
                        {% if company.custom_many1 %}
                            {% for selected in company.custom_many1.all %}
                                <option selected="selected" name="custommany1" value="{{ selected }}">{{ selected }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% for option in custommany1_options.all %}
                                {% if option not in company.custom_many1.all %}
                                        <option name="custommany1" value="{{ option }}">{{ option }}</option>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% for option in custommany1_options %}
                                <option name="custommany1" value="{{ option }}">{{ option }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </select></p>
                {% else %}
                    <input type="hidden" id="company-custommany1">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#company-form-submit').click(function() {
            var company_id = document.getElementById("companyID").value;
            var company_name = document.getElementById("id_company-company_name").value;
            var company_custommany1 = document.getElementById("company-custommany1").value;

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'companies:company_update' %}",
            data: {
                'company_id': company_id,
                'company_name': company_name,
                'company_custommany1': company_custommany1,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", '{{ csrf_token }}');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.company-form-container').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page. They are unique by definition

Comment: For a multiple `<select>` jQuery `val()` will return an array of selected values

Comment: @charlietfl -- Using val() hasn't worked.  The getlist('company_custommany1') returns an empty array when using val.  Should I use something else?  When I use the above code, I get the first value in the getlist.  Does val required something else?

Comment: Should work fine if you removed duplicate element ID's and have something selected as in this demo https://jsfiddle.net/gzmd5rdv/

Comment: @charlietfl -- thats funny.  It works when I use stringify, but not when I don't.

Comment: Is your back end expecting  json request? Or a form-encoded request?

Comment: json, which I manually assign each value to the manytomany field.  So now I need to figure out how to turn that string into an array to iterate over.

Comment: You need to stringify the data object and set contentType if expecting json in back end

Comment: And then use regex on the string to pull out the values?  There's got to be a simpler solution, no?

Comment: No idea why you would ever need to do that

Comment: I got it to work with the regex.  The stringify comes back with [u'["Marketing","SEO"]'] which wasn't able to be json.loaded or dumped because the string was "corrupted" and couldn't use the ast.literal_eval either.  Did I miss something simpler to do to turn it back into an array for iterating over the values?

Comment: No idea how you got that as value....something very strange going on

Comment: well marketing and seo were choices for the select options.  What's weird is the initial stringify is a list, but it can't be iterated.  Once I get the same values in the regex, that list is able to be iterated.  Not sure why I can't iterate over the values in the initial stringify.

Comment: @charlietfl -- thanks for the help!